# jmeter url formatting questions

Tags: jmeter

Trying to load test a site using a tool i dont quite understand against a formatting standard I cant seem to crack. so:

```
somesite.com/users/sign_in/service:accounts?redirect=/
```

is the url in question. While I (think) I understand what this url is doing, what are my steps to test in jmeter?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to test in Jmeter depend largely on what you're trying to test.

As a starting point, I would recommend recording logging into the site, so you capture every parameter that's being sent along with its value.

You can then parametrize these values as needed.  It looks like once someone logs in, they get redirected to another page.  Mostly likely when you record, you'll see the login page and then a landing page captured.

Comment: appreciate the response. what is happening is i am going from a somesite.com, click login, which directs to subdomain.somesite.com/users/sign_in/service:accounts?redirect=/ at which point you enter credentials and goto subdomain.somesite.com/. In fiddler, the result is to goto root of subdomain.somesite.com, so that is working. The next question would be how to record in jmeter the request 'subdomain.somesite.com/users/sign_in/service:accounts?redirect=/' Is it an httpRequest that I track, is it broken up and the path added in the path field, how is the ':' handled... thanks for insight.

Comment: When you record it, JMeter will automatically capture all the redirect pages and subdomains. Most likely the redirect will be an HTTP Request to "/users/sign_in/service:accounts" with parameter for redirect with value '/'